# Prove that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{t^x+1}dt = \frac\pi x \csc \frac\pi x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I'm stuck on this identity:

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{t^x+1}dt = \frac\pi x \csc \frac\pi x
$$

Could someone show me a proof for this?

#### What I've tried:

I've thrown a bunch of substitutions and integration by parts at this, but they haven't led me to the answer. I did, however, find these identites:
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{t^x+1}dt = \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-2}}{t^x+1}dt = \int_0^1\left( \frac{1-t}t \right)^{1/x}dt
$$
But none of these seem to lead anywhere helpful.

I also tried introducing another variable to turn it into something similar to the Laplace Transform, but I'm not very familiar with methods like that, so they've led nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Beta function
\begin{eqnarray*}
B(a,b) = \int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt = \frac{ \Gamma(a) \Gamma(b) } {\Gamma(a+b)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the well known gamma function identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{ \pi} { \sin( \pi z)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, but I should have given some more context: I'm following along with a proof of the very identity you showed, so in my case, using this would be circular.